# Carrito de compras con PHP y MySQL que agrega productos repetidos

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras con PHP y MySQL y si agrega productos, pero el problema es que agrega el mismo una y otra vez, aunque agregue otro diferente, siempre inserta el mismo. Incluso cuando refresco la pagina lo agrega automaticamente.
Aqui esta una parte del codigo...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="columnader">
<?php
session_start();
$servidor="localhost";
    $usuario="root";
    $pass="";
    $based="pruebastarento";
    $conser=mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $pass);
    $conbd=mysqli_select_db($conser,$based) or die (mysqli_error())

    $por_pagina = 6;
    if (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
        # code...
        $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
    }else{
        $pagina = 1;
    }

    # La pagina inicia en 0 y se multiplica por $por_pagina
    $empieza = ($pagina-1) * $por_pagina;
    # Seleccionar los registros de la tabla usuarios con LIMIT

    $query="SELECT * FROM  `tornillos` LIMIT $empieza, $por_pagina";
    $run=mysqli_query($conser,$query);

    echo"<table id='tlista' style=padding-bottom:5%;>";
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
    {
        $vars1=$fila['ID_TOR'];
        $vars2=$fila['NOM_TOR'];
        $vars3=$fila['PRECIO_TOR'];
        echo"<div style='width:300px;height:auto;'>";
        echo"ID del producto: ".$vars1."" ;
        echo "<hr>";
        echo"<center><h1 style=font-size:20px;>".$vars2."</h1></center>";
        echo"<img src='imagenes/catalogo/".$fila['FOTO_TOR']."' 
        style='height:60px;width:50%;' alt='Image Not Available'>";
        echo"<p>".$fila['DESC_TOR']."</p><br>";
        echo "<hr>";
        echo"<h2>USD$ ".$vars3."</h2>";
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<button class='buttoncarrito' 
        onclick='javascript:InsertarCarrito();'><h4 style='text-
        align:center;'>Add to cart</h4></button>";
        echo"</div>";
    };
    echo"</table>";
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function InsertarCarrito()
    {
        <?php
        # code...
        $request = "INSERT INTO carrito                         
        (ID_PROCAR,NOMBRE_PROCAR,CANT_PROCAR,PRECIO_PROCAR,CLIENTE_PROCAR) 
        VALUES('".$vars1."','".$vars2."','1','". 
        $vars3."','".$_SESSION['login_user']."')";
        mysqli_query($conser, $request);
        #$listo=mysqli_query($conser,$insert);#

        if (true) {echo "alert('Add to cart');";}
        else{echo "alert('Not add to cart);";}
        $vars1="";
        $vars2="";
        $vars3="";
        ?>

    }
    </script>
```

Tambien dejo unas imagenes donde se puede ver que sigue agregando el mismo
...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora el carrito...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola amigo te recomendaria que vieras este tutorial de como crear un cart en php : https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/06/creating-simple-shopping-cart-with-php/comment-page-1 es muy bueno usan PHP 5 te recomiendo que lo veas.

Comment: Tu código es algo _extraño_, por esta línea: `SELECT * FROM  tornillos LIMIT $empieza, $por_pagina ` y luego dentro de un bucle llamas a la función `InsertarCarrito()` que te inserta seguramente varias veces el mismo registro. Deberías, pienso, tener una variable que almacene la cantidad y que luego inserte en el carrito los productos que han sido seleccionados y las cantidades.

Comment: @A.Cedano inserta el mismo cuando refresco la pagina y cuando quiero añadir otro producto agrega el mismo de todas maneras ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Lo primero que te diría es que separes el código, es decir, las vistas de los productos en un archivo y las funciones o acciones del carrito en otro.  Básicamente se inserta el mismo por qué siempre le estas pasando los mismo valores a la función InsertarCarrito() de js, piensa que el código php que hay dentro de esa función se va a ejecutar solo una vez  y en el lado del servidor y las variables **$vars1, $vars2** están tomando los valores del último ciclo del while anterior, no acumulando dichos valores. Ahora no tengo mucho tiempo, pero si no te dan una respuesta luego te pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: @Xerif Te lo agradeceria mucho por que aun no he podido resolverlo

Comment: Una pregunta por qué guardas en la base de datos el carrito? No es más fácil hacerlo en sesión? A ver si te puedo dar un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Te pondré un ejemplo básico de como hacer un carrito almacenandolo en una base de datos.

Lo primero sería crear las tablas basicas, en este caso para el ejemplo utilizare 3 lo mas basicas posible, **clientes, productos y carritos**.

Creamos la base de datos **carrito**

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema carrito
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `carrito` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `carrito` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `carrito`.`productos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carrito`.`productos` (
  `idProducto` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `carrito`.`carritos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carrito`.`carritos` (
  `idCarrito` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCliente` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idProducto` INT NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCarrito`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `carrito`.`clientes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carrito`.`clientes` (
  `idCliente` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCliente`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Creamos una clase basica para la conexion

```
class Conexion
{
    private $servidor ="localhost";
    private $usuario ="carrito";
    private $contrasena ="carrito";
    private $nombre_bd ="carrito";
    public $link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->contrasena, $this->nombre_bd) or die("Error con la base de datos.");
    }
}
```

Creamos nuestra clase basica del carrito y extendemos de la clase conexión, explicado en los comentarios de la clase que hace cada cosa.

```
class CarritoController extends Conexion
{
    // Creamos 2 variables una para armacenar el carrito y otra para guardar el id cliente 
    public $carrito = array();
    private $idCliente = null;

    public function __construct($idCliente)
    {
        /* Inicializamos la conexion a la base de datos */
        parent::__construct();
        /* Establecemos el cliente */
        $this->idCliente = $idCliente;
        /* recuperamos el estado del carrito */
        $this->show();
    }

    /* recupera y retorna el carrito de la base de datos */
    public function show()
    {
        /* Recuperar el carrito */
        $sql = 'SELECT idCarrito, idProducto, idCliente, cantidad FROM carritos WHERE idCliente = ?';
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->idCliente);
        $stmt->execute();

        $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
        // Reseteamos el carrito antes de actualizarlo, por si acaso tiene valores de antes.
        $this->carrito = array();
        // Almacenamos el carrito en nuestra variable 
        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $this->carrito[$row['idProducto']] = $row['cantidad'];
        }

        // Liberamos resultados
        $resultado->free_result();

        // Devolvemos el carrito
        return $this->carrito;
    }

    /* Inserta y establece la cantidad de un producto */
    public function insert($idProducto,  $cantidad=1)
    {
        // Comprobamos si existe el producto en el carrito
        if(array_key_exists($idProducto, $this->carrito))
        {
            // si existe actualizamos sumando la cantidad
            $sql = 'UPDATE carritos SET cantidad = cantidad + ? WHERE idProducto = ? AND idCliente = ? ';
        }
        else
        {
            // si no existe insertamos
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO carritos (cantidad, idProducto, idCliente) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
        }

        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('iii', $cantidad, $idProducto, $this->idCliente);
        $stmt->execute();

        // recuperamos el estado del carrito despues de los cambios
        $this->show();

        return true;
    }

    /* Elimina un producto del carrito */
    public function delete($idProducto)
    {           
        // Comprobamos si existe el producto en el carrito
        if(array_key_exists($idProducto, $this->carrito))
        {
            // si existe eliminamos el producto
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM carritos WHERE idProducto = ? AND idCliente = ? ';
            $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $idProducto, $this->idCliente);
            $stmt->execute();

            // recuperamos el estado del carrito despues de los cambios
            $this->show();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /* Descarta todo el carrito */
    public function destroy()
    {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM carritos WHERE idCliente = ? ';
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->idCliente);
        $stmt->execute();

        // recuperamos el estado del carrito despues de los cambios
        $this->show();

        return true;
    }

    /* Elimina los artuculos que tencgan cantidad menor a 1 y cierra la conexion*/
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM carritos WHERE idCliente = ? AND cantidad < 1';
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->idCliente);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Como usarla

```
// Inicializamos el objeto con el idCliente
$carrito = new CarritoController(1);

// insertar un producto, pasando el idProducto y la cantidad
$carrito->insert(3, 5);

// Restar cantidad a un producto, pasamos idProducto y cantidad en negativo
$carrito->insert(3, -2);

// Eliminar un producto del carrito, pasamos el idProducto
$carrito->insert(3);

// Retornar el estado del carrito
$articulos = $carrito->show();

// Vaciar o eliminar el carrito
$carrito->destroy();
```

Obviamente este código es bastante mejorable pero espero que te de una idea basica de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que al pintarse la página, la función InsertarCarrito quedará en el HTML pintada con el INSERT con las variables $vars1, $vars2, etc. sustituidas por el ultimo valor que han tenido al hacer el bucle anteriormente en el código.

Esto es porque no puedes utilizar código PHP dentro de JavaScript asumiendo que va a ser dinámico.

La manera correcta de hacer lo que quieres hacer, es utilizar llamadas AJAX a un PHP si quieres utilizar JavaScript, o puedes no utilizar JS en absoluto replanteando el código de la siguiente manera, que sería lo mas sencillo:

Olvidate de la funcion InsertarCarrito, y pinta el botón de añadir el producto al carrito de la siguiente manera:

```
echo "<a href='?accion=insertar&id=".$vars1."&nombre=".$vars2."&precio=".$vars3."&pagina=".$pagina."'><button class='buttoncarrito'><h4 style='text-align:center;'>Add to cart</h4></button>";
```

De esta manera, cada producto tendrá un enlace que pasará de vuelta al script PHP el id, nombre y precio a insertar, y la pagina actual en la que nos encontramos para no perderla.

Arriba de todo, justo después de declarar $condb:

```
$conbd=mysqli_select_db($conser,$based) or die (mysqli_error())

if (isset($_GET['accion']) && $_GET['accion'] == "insertar") {
    $request = "INSERT INTO carrito                         
    (ID_PROCAR,NOMBRE_PROCAR,CANT_PROCAR,PRECIO_PROCAR,CLIENTE_PROCAR) 
    VALUES('".$_GET['id']."','".$_GET['nombre']."','1','". 
    $_GET['precio']."','".$_SESSION['login_user']."')";
    mysqli_query($conser, $request);
    echo "<script>alert('Add to cart');</script>";
}
```

De esta manera, si al script PHP le llega por GET la variable accion, y esta es igual a "insertar", actuamos en consecuencia (Es decir, insertamos los valores que también nos han llegado por GET en base de datos, y mostramos un alert por javascript.

Answer (score 0):

se estan insertando los registro ya que de primer plano se ejecuta PHP con el insert que as metido en esa funcion de javascript lo que debes hacer es utilizar AJAX para que envie los datos y los registre mediante un request

Ejemplo creas tu archivo

> agregarProducto.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$servidor="localhost";
$usuario="root";
$pass="";
$based="pruebastarento";
$conser=mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $pass);
$conbd=mysqli_select_db($conser,$based) or die (mysqli_error());
$vars1 = $_POST['ID_PROCAR'];
$vars2 =$_POST['NOMBRE_PROCAR'];
$vars3 = $_POST['PRECIO_PROCAR'];
$request = "INSERT INTO carrito(ID_PROCAR,NOMBRE_PROCAR,CANT_PROCAR,PRECIO_PROCAR,CLIENTE_PROCAR) VALUES('".$vars1."','".$vars2."','1','".$vars3."','".$_SESSION['login_user']."')";
mysqli_query($conser, $request);
?>
```

y en tu javascript:

```
function InsertarCarrito(id, name, price) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "agregarProducto.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("ID_PROCAR="+id+"&NOMBRE_PROCAR="+name+"&PRECIO_PROCAR="+price);
}
```

modificas el boton de agregar por:

```
echo "<button class='buttoncarrito' onclick='javascript:InsertarCarrito('".$vars1."', '".$vars2."', '".$vars3."');'><h4 style='text-align:center;'>Add to cart</h4></button>";
```