# ¿Cómo crear un carrito de compras correctamente?

Tags: php, bootstrap, mysqli

Quiero hacer un **carrito de compras** con el siguiente codigo de `productos.php`:

```
 <?php
 require "templates/conexion.php";
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
        <div class="row">
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel carousel-fade slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="templates/imgs/slider-producto-2.jpg" alt="no image" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="col-md-6 pull-right bg-lim-c caption-lim-right">
          <p>Las mejores marcas</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">

        <img src="templates/imgs/slider-producto-4.jpg" alt="no image" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="col-md-6 pull-left bg-lim-c caption-lim-left">
          <p>Atención Personalizada</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <br>
    <!-- controles -->
    <a class="left carousel-control color-lim" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control color-lim" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
 </div>
            <div class="shop-items">
        <?php
    if( !isset($_GET['show']) ){
        include "busqueda/motor.php";
            $filas = mysqli_query($cnx, $consulta);
            while($columnas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filas)){

            ?>    
            <div class="item flex">
                            <!-- Imagen -->
                        <a href="index.php?section=1&show=<?php echo $columnas['id_producto']; ?>">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="productos/<?php echo $columnas['foto']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $columnas['nombre']; ?>">
                        </a>
                            <!-- Detalle -->
                            <div class="item-dtls">
                                <!-- title -->
                                <h5><a href="index.php?section=1&show=<?php echo $columnas['id_producto']; ?>"><?php
                                $title = $columnas['nombre'];
                                $newtext = substr($title, 0, 22) . "...";
                                echo $newtext;?></a></h5>
                                <!-- precio-->
                                <span class="price lblue">$<?php echo $columnas['precio']; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ecom bg-lim d-inline">
                                <a class="btn btn-perso" href="index.php?section=1&show=<?php echo $columnas['id_producto']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <span style="color:white">| </span>
                                <a class="btn btn-perso">+<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
   </div>
    <br>
  <?php
        }else{
            ?>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="content-wrapper-pl">  
          <?php 
      $p = $_GET['show'];
      $consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos INNER JOIN marcas ON productos.id_marca = marcas.id_marca WHERE productos.id_producto = $p";
      $fila = mysqli_query($cnx, $consulta);
      $columnas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fila);
    ?>
    <div class="item-container">  
      <div class="container-fluid p-1 m-auto b-lim"> 
        <div class="col-md-4 m-auto text-center">
          <div class="p-1 service-image-left">
            <center >
              <a style="cursor:zoom-in" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verfoto">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid img-responsive m-auto" src="productos/<?php echo $columnas['foto']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $columnas['nombre'] ?>">
       </a>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="product-title"><?php echo $columnas['nombre']; ?>
 </div>
           <div class="product-desc"> <?php echo $columnas['presentacion']; ?> </div>
          <div class="product-rating"><i class="fa fa-star gold"></i> <i class="fa fa-star gold"></i> <i class="fa fa-star gold"></i> <i class="fa fa-star gold"></i> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i> </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="product-price">$ <?php echo $columnas['precio']; ?> <moneda>ARS</moneda></div>
          <hr>
          <div class="stock"><p>Stock: 
            <?php
            if (strcasecmp($columnas['stock'], 'si') === 0) {
            echo '<span class="product-stock st-si">' .$columnas['stock'] ."</span>";
          }
          else{
          echo '<span class="product-stock st-no">' .$columnas['stock'] ."</span>";
          }
            ?></p> </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="btn-group cart">
            <button type="button" class="btn bg-lim white" alt="Agregar al carrito" title="Agregar al carrito">
              Añadir al carrito <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
     </div>
    <div class="modal fade z-10000" id="verfoto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:65%;">
    <div class="modal-content" data-dismiss="modal">
      <a style="position: absolute;top:1em;right:1em;cursor:pointer;" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
  <img class="img-fluid img-responsive m-auto" src="productos/<?php echo $columnas['foto']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $columnas['nombre'] ?>" title="<?php echo $columnas['nombre'] ?>">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
    <div class="container-fluid-pl">   
      <div class="col-md-12 product-info">
          <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs menu-pl">

            <li class="active"><a href="#service-one" data-toggle="tab">DESCRIPCIÓN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service-three" data-toggle="tab">CALIFICACIÓNES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service-two" data-toggle="tab">PAGOS & ENVIOS</a>
  </li>

          </ul>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content container-fluid">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="service-one">

              <section class="container-pl product-info">
                <h3>Descripción</h3>
                <p><?php echo $columnas['descripcion']; ?></p>
              </section>

            </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-two">

            <section class="container-pl product-info">
              <div class="col-md-6">
              <h3 style="margin:0 auto;">Medios de pago</h3>
              <hr>
                <p>En ********* utilizamos los medios de pago brindados por <a href="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar" target="_BLANK"><span style="color:rgba(0,0,255,.8);">MERCADOPAGO</span></a>.</p>
                </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p style="font-size:1.5em;">En hasta 36 cuotas con tarjeta</p>
                <p style="font-size:1.1em;color:green;"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Acreditación instantánea.</p>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="visa d-inline-block"></div>
                  <div class="amex d-inline-block"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </section>

          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-three">

            <?php
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM comentarios INNER JOIN usuarios ON 
    comentarios.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario WHERE comentarios.id_producto = $p 
    ORDER BY comentarios.id_comentario DESC";
    $filas = mysqli_query($cnx, $consulta);
    while($columnas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filas) ){
            ?>

            <div class="card-body comentarios p-1 container-fluid">
                                    <h3>
                                        <div class="reviews-rating stars-5">
    </div>
                                    </h3>
                                    <!--Commentario-->
                                    <p itemprop="reviewBody" id="comentario"><?php echo $columnas['comentario']; ?></p>

                                    <!--Footer comentario -->
                                    <div class="footer">
                                            <img class="avatar z-depth-1" src="templates/imgs/avatars/1.jpg" alt="Foto comment">
                                            <span class="author" itemprop="author"><?php echo $columnas['nombre']; ?></span>
                                            <span><smaller><?php echo $columnas['fecha']; ?></smaller></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="pull-right text-muted" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">                 <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">                 <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">                 <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
            <?php
    } 
      if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
    ?>  

      <form action="templates/agregar/guardarComentario.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="comentario" placeholder="Califica este producto." class="comentario_box">
      <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_usuario']?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="producto" value="<?php echo $p;?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar calificación" class="btn-lim bg-lim">
      </form>

    <?php   
    }
    ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5 class="m-0">Productos Relacionados</h5>
            <div class="col-md-9" style="color:red;">
                <small>Contenido faltante</small>
            </div>
        </div>

            </div>
          </div>

  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </div>
```

La idea en principal es que utilizando `productos.php` el usuario al dar **click** en:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-lim white" 
 alt="Agregar al carrito" title="Agregar al carrito">
          Añadir al carrito 
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
```

Se **actualice el carrito** de compras mientras el usuario **sigue navegando.**

Una vez el **usuario finalice su "compra"**, imaginar una navbar con un icono de carrito / shop y que se haya actualizado, por ejemplo con el numero "15".
El usuario tiene dos opciónes dar click en ese mismo "icono" o ir a  `"Mi Carrito"` o `"Finalizar Compra"`

Hecho esto, tengo 2 opciones en mente (por ahora, sugerencias son aceptadas):

1. Guardar productos que el usuario eligió en `$x = array();`
2. Guardar mediante `$_SESSION` la selección del usuario.

Y para finalizar el `finalizar.php` o `comprar.php` (carrito.php).
Donde tomando por `$variable` o `$_SESSION` , reflejaría en una `<table>`, los productos seleccionados.

El núcleo en sí de navegación de la página esta enfocado en un:

```
   if( isset($_GET['section'])){
    switch($_GET['section']){
        case 1:
            include "productos.php";
            break;
```

etc...

Comment: La pregunta parece un poco basada en opiniones, por otro lado no se si buscas más una respuesta conceptual de como realizarlo o un ejemplo al uso. Hace algún tiempo aporte [este ejemplo de un carrito almacenado en base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82573/carrito-de-compras-con-php-y-mysql-que-agrega-productos-repetidos/85706#85706), no es completo pero puede proporcionar una idea.

Comment: **Gracias** por el aporte, me sirvió en cuanto a entender como manejar un carrito en base a BD. Busco un ejemplo al uso o al código que brinde de `productos.php` Con los ejemplos que encontre estoy intentando hacer que el usuario al agregar o quitar productos, no se actualize toda la pagina (f5), sino que se actualize el contenido. ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Para actualizar sin refrescar la página, puedes usar AJAX.